# How to get share count in SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin for whhtsapp Invites?

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap, socialshare

My current app is being developed in IONIC-3. We have need to track the no of invite send from referee using whats app and Facebook . Referee is awarded with no of invitations sent , not based on no of Installs . What is the easiest way to achieve this ? Is it part of  SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin already or this needs to be customize to get this share count .

Answer (score 0):

I have asked recently the official developer on Twitter, He said they don't support any stats on sharing with their plugin.
I think it something that can be done writing your own code and updating a DB.